# nested sql queries inside for loop node.js not working

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, node.js

I have a for loop going through a JSON array - with help from [this stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7136518/insert-data-with-node-mysql-in-loop)

Whilst looping the script does the following:

```
- Does the JSON item exist in the tables?
- if yes
    - Is the data different?
    - if yes
        - Update
    - if no
        - Do nothing
- if no
    -insert into database
```

I found this question which allowed me to query on each for loop so I am able to get the names from the JSON and query them correctly :

```
for(var i=0; i<content.prices.length; i++) {
        var price = content.prices[i].price
        var itemName = content.prices[i].market_hash_name;

        var q = "SELECT * FROM prices WHERE item = ?";
        (function() {
            var iNameCopy = itemName;
            var priceCopy = price;
            connection.query(q, iNameCopy, function (err, results) {
                if (err) throw err;
                if(results.length === 1) {
                    logger.info(iNameCopy + " does exist");
                }
                else if (results.length === 0){
                    logger.info(iNameCopy + " does not exist");
                }
            });
        }());
    }
```

Moving onto adding the if statement inside `results.length === 1`

```
for(var i=0; i<content.prices.length; i++) {
        var price = content.prices[i].price
        var itemName = content.prices[i].market_hash_name;

        var q = "SELECT * FROM prices WHERE item = ?";
        (function() {
            var iNameCopy = itemName;
            var priceCopy = price;
            connection.query(q, iNameCopy, function (err, results) {
                if (err) throw err;
                if(results.length === 1) {
                    if(parseFloat(results[0].current_price) != parseFloat(priceCopy)) { 
                       logger.info(iNameCopy + " does exist with old price: " + results[0].current_price + " and new price: " + priceCopy);
                   }
                }
                else if (results.length === 0){
                    logger.info(iNameCopy + " does not exist");
                }
            });
        }());
    }
```

Again this is still working.

Now finally replacing those loggers with new sql queries is where the code stumbles. The for loop runs as if I keep the loggers they display however the sql query loggers do not display:

I tried both this way I found from the other stack question and without wrapping it in a function but neither worked. Any suggestions?

```
for(var i=0; i<content.prices.length; i++) {
        var price = content.prices[i].price
        var itemName = content.prices[i].market_hash_name;

        var q = "SELECT * FROM prices WHERE item = ?";
        (function() {
            var iNameCopy = itemName;
            var priceCopy = price;
            connection.query(q, iNameCopy, function (err, results) {
                if (err) throw err;
                if(results.length === 1) {
                    if(parseFloat(results[0].current_price) != parseFloat(priceCopy)) {
                        var sql2="UPDATE `prices` SET `current_price` = ?, `timeStamp` = ? WHERE `item` = ?";
                        (function() {
                            var iNameCopy2 = iNameCopy
                            var priceCopy2 = priceCopy
                            connection.query(sql2, [priceCopy2, 'Now()', iNameCopy2], function(err,results){
                                logger.info("UPDATE: " + iNameCopy2 + ' has been updated with price ' + priceCopy2);
                            });
                        }());
                    }
                }
                else if (results.length === 0){
                    var sql3="INSERT INTO `prices` (`item`, `current_price`, `timeStamp`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
                    (function() {
                        var iNameCopy3 = iNameCopy
                        var priceCopy3 = priceCopy
                        connection.query(sql3, [iNameCopy3, priceCopy3, 'Now()'], function(err,results){
                            logger.info("INSERT: " + iNameCopy3 + ' has been added with price ' + priceCopy3);
                        });
                    }());
                }
            });
        }());
    }
```

note: I have my database connection on the outside of the for loop:

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection(db_access);
    connection.connect(function(err){
      if(err){
        logger.error('Error connecting to Db');
        return;
      }
    });
```

Comment: Hope it made it pretty clear. But the query doesn't run and the loggers inside the nested query isn't logged. The sql query itself  is fine (tested directly in database) but it just doesn't want to query. The for loop keeps running as normal though. No errors are shown

Comment: @Ofir I have noticed that it seem to loop once then loop again doing the inner sql queries. the for loop is around 7000 big so it took a while to loop the first time. I kept closing the node as there was no movement at the beginning. Any idea why this is?

Comment: No idea, try to add more logging in key parts of the code like when the loop starts and ends and such.

Comment: @Ofir i've logged it all. if i put a log just outside of the sql2 query and inside the if price != price that will log straight away. then all of a sudden after 7000 loops the query loggers started to log.

Comment: Try to terminate the connection after your query - connection.query().. then connection.end(); to release it.

Comment: Just to confirm, add that after sql2 and sql3 queries?

Comment: Yes after any query to clear up the connection for the next queries.

Comment: as expected I got the following error: ` Cannot enqueue Query after invoking quit.`

Comment: Ah.. well it's either than or my other suggestion to put all the code in the connection.connect, but wait for other suggestions.