# How to force order of execution of functions

Tags: node.js, api, promise, vuejs3, quasar-framework

What I need to happen is to take a list of "dvirs" and get the lat and lng from each.
Take the lat and lng and get an map address. Then take each lat and lng and create an address for a static image.  So far Have not found a way to complete in my order. When I run this, the router runs before the addresses are returned.
My order and code is below.

- pass data to function
- loop through data

  - get physical address
  - build static map image
- route finished data to display/print page

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36958121/node-js-promises-not-forcing-order-execution-of-functions/36958151#36958151) helped but my code is still not completed in order.

```
function printMultiple(dvirs) {
      console.log("one: ");
      return mapDvirPromise(dvirs).then(function (dvir) {
        console.log("four: ");
        routePrint(dvirs);
      });
    }

let mapDvirPromise = function (data) {
  console.log("data: ", data);

  console.log("two");
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    data.map((dvir) => {
      let lat = dvir.position.latitude;
      let lng = dvir.position.longitude;
      console.log("latlng: ", lat + ", " + lng);
      if (lat != undefined) {
        geoapifyApi({
          method: "get",
          url:
            "reverse?lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + lng + "&apiKey=" + process.env.GEOAPIFY_KEY,
        })
          .then((response) => {
            console.log("response: ", response.data.features[0].properties.formatted);
            dvir.position.address = response.data.features[0].properties.formatted;
          })
          .then(() => {
            //get map from geoapify
            console.log("enter ur fix");
            let url =
              
              "https://maps.geoapify.com/v1/staticmap?style=osm-carto&width=450&height=300&center=lonlat:" +
              lng +
              "," +
              lat +
              "&zoom=14&marker=lonlat:" +
              lng +
              "," +
              lat +
              ";type:awesome;color:%2319b8fc;size:large + "&apiKey=" + process.env.GEOAPIFY_KEY";
            console.log("leave url");
            dvir.position.map = toDataUrl(url);
          })
          .catch(() => {
            dvir.position.address = "No Address Found";
            reject(err);
          });
      } else {
        dvir.position.address = "No Address Found";
      }
      console.log("three: ");
    });
    resolve(dvirs.value);
  });
};

function routePrint(dvirs) {
  console.log("routePrint: ", dvirs);
  let address = "DvirViews";
  router.push({
    name: address,
    params: { dvirs: JSON.stringify(dvirs) },
  });
}
```

The dvirs data is coming from selected records of a table and the "printMultiple" function is called in a button.

```
<q-table
      v-model:selected="selected"
      :loading="loading"
      :title="tableTitle"
      :rows="rows"
      row-key="dvirDate"
      :columns="columns"
      :filter="filter"
      :rows-per-page-options="[12, 50, 100, 0]"
      @row-click="onRowClick"
      selection="multiple"
    >
      <template v-slot:top>
        <q-btn
          class="q-mt-md print-hide"
          color="primary"
          label="View multiple"
          @click="printMultiple(selected)"
        />
```

I have tried many ways, before the route, after the route, with Promise.all, as functions, using .then..... so far nothing keeps the order, my code will continue without the calls or function finishing. Does anyone have ideas? I am even interested in where I can learn the solution.

Comment: Where does the `dvirs` come from that you use in `resolve(dvirs.value)`? Also, the `resolve` happens before the `geoapifyApi` (which returns also a promise) has completed.

Comment: dvirs comes from the selected records of a table. dvirs is an array. for the resolve how do I call after the map is done?

Comment: I don't understand what your code is supposed to do. Whether it works depends on where `dvirs` is declared (not shown in your code). Is that a global variable?

Comment: The Promise returned by `mapDvirPromise` should only resolve once all API calls have been resolved.  You'll need to collect all the API call promises into an array and watch for them all to resolve with [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).  Only then should `mapDvirPromise` resolve allowing `routePrint` to finally be called

Comment: @HeikoTheißen I have add code above

Comment: @yoduh thank you, I understand your ideas but do not know how to implement them. Do I need to separate the functions into individual promises?  Would you post a solution?

Comment: I have tried many ways, before the route, after the route, with Promise.all, as functions, using .then..... so far nothing keeps the order, my code will continue without the calls or function finishing.  Does anyone have ideas? I am even interested in where I can learn the solution.